# Debugging not starting at breakpoint

Tags: c++, debugging, qt4

I made a program in Qt creator for c++ using opencv libraries.But i want to debug it and have set a breakpoint at the desired line.  However no matter where I set the breakpoint the debug mode always starts at the first line of the main() program.How can I solve this?

Comment: That's the default behavior of the debugger yes. Just hit `Run` to go on ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by deleting *.pro.user file and restarting IDE.

Comment: Yes. I also just solved the problem by restarting the IDE. Thanks!!